# Java -> LDAP account password encryption

Tags: java, spring, encryption, passwords, ldap

I have an Ldap directory synchronised from a microsoft active directory.

This Ldap contain many account, each account have a password attribute.

I must develop a java program where a user have to log with his AD login and password, but i don't know the method employed to correctly encrypt the password typed.

I need it to compare with the ldap password.

I also need to bind new account with the same password encryption.

Anyone know how to do?

Comment: why do you need to encrypt the password? If your java program uses LDAP to authenticate the user, the you could just use the bind() api to verify the credentials.

Comment: I already connect to LDAP directory , now I want to create new account on ldap (this is done) and the user will have the choice of his password. My Question is how to encrypt password??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution with spring,

here the method to test login/pass couple :

```
AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "person")).and(new EqualsFilter("cn", login));
boolean authentifie = ldapTemplate.authenticate(DistinguishedName.EMPTY_PATH, filter.toString(), password);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you can use a BIND with SSL, but that's considered kind of the lame way to go about it and may be disabled on some systems. A truly secure way is using SPNEGO-GSS, and this is not trivial. You have to learn and understand about Kerberos. That's a long topic but you can start with [reading and going through everything here](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/)